# Why am I getting this error: fatal error - array index out of range?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, imageview

I have 2 view controllers: a `cameraVC` and a `detailVC`. The camera is an `AVFoundation` camera that can capture and then select pictures, which then populates 4 small `imageViews` on my `detailVC`. I am trying to swipe between the two VCs so that when you hit **'yes'** on the `cameraVC`, that then adds that to one of the 4 `imageViews`. I am currently using for-loops to achieve this, and below is the code I have in my detail VCs.

It works when I first load the app and take a few pics, but when I swipe back to my `cameraVC` and then back to my `detailVC`, the app crashes and logs error above.

In my code, I am attempting to set the `imageViewArray` to however many images there are in my `imageArray`. Then each time I go back to the `detailVC`, I am to clear my `imageView.images` and re-assign them. For some reason, it's not working. Any ideas why?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if imageArray.count == 1 {
        imageViewArray += [imageView1]
    } else if imageArray.count == 2 {
        imageViewArray += [imageView1,imageView2]
    } else if imageArray.count == 3 {
        imageViewArray += [imageView1,imageView2,imageView3]
    } else if imageArray.count == 4 {
        imageViewArray += [imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4]
    }

    for ima in imageViewArray {
        if ima.image != nil {
        ima.image = nil
        }
    }

    for (index, imageView) in imageViewArray.enumerate() {
        imageView.image = imageArray[index]
    }   
}
```

Comment: For readability's sake, I would suggest in your `for` statement, use `for image in imageViewArray` instead of `ima`. It'll make your code much easier to figure out in 6 months when you go back to it or if someone else is trying to follow along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line

```
imageViewArray = []
```

in the beginning of your `viewWillAppear`.

Or change your assignment to the `imageViewArray` in all 4 branches to something like:

```
imageViewArray = [imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4] // removed the "+"
```

The problem you are encountering here is that the method gets called when the view gets presented the first time AND when some presented view gets dismissed / popped again causing your view to appear again.

The result of that is that the `imageViewArray` still contains the imageviews from the last iteration. Adding the images again causes the array to get larger.

Assume that you had 3 images the first time, now the second time you have 4 images. Therefore you enter the last else section and add 4 new elements to the array, causing it to have 7 elements while the imageArray still only has 4. Now you iterate over all `imageViewArray` entries and try to access the `imageArray` at up to index 6 while the array only contains value until index 3 -> **crash**.

Note that it was annoying writing this answer because you have too many variables that all sound and look the same `imageView`, `image`, `imageArray`, `imageViewArray`, `ima`, `imageViewX`. Please try to find better names.

Comment: you are a very smart bloke, thank you very much for your help.